# Finding relation between matrix $S$ and matrix $M$ for wave propagation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, s-matrix-theory, unitarity

we have the same Scattering matrix concept in RF as in quantum physics however, I couldnt derive an expression for the $S$ matrix using the $M$ matrix elements and vice-versa. How can I derive eq 1.13 from eq 1.10 and eq 1.12

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\b_2 \end{bmatrix} =
 \begin{bmatrix}
S_{11} & S_{12} \\
S_{21} & S_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\a_2
\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

$$b_1= S_{11}a_1 + S_{12}a_2 \\
b_2= S_{21}a_1 + S_{22}a_2 \tag{2}\label{2}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}b_2 \\a_2 \end{bmatrix} =
 \begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} & M_{12} \\
M_{21} & M_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\b_1
\end{bmatrix} \tag{3}\label{3}$$
$$b_2= M_{11}a_1 + M_{12}b_1 \\
a_2= M_{21}a_1 + M_{22}b_1 \tag{4}\label{4}$$

Now rearrange $\eqref{2}$ as follows:

$$a_2=-\frac{S_{11}}{S_{12}}a_1+\frac{1}{S_{12}}b_1\\
b_2=(S_{21}-\frac{S_{11}S_{22}}{S_{12}})a_1+\frac{S_{22}}{S_{12}}b_1$$ that is

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} & M_{12} \\
M_{21} & M_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
S_{21}-\frac{S_{11}S_{22}}{S_{12}}& \frac{S_{22}}{S_{12}} \\
-\frac{S_{11}}{S_{12}} & \frac{1}{S_{12}} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is what you wanted to prove.