# Relationship between $S$ matrix elements and $T$ matrix elements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, s-matrix-theory, unitarity

In hadron physics, we define the $S$ matrix as $S=I+iT$, where $T$ is transition matrix. But on the question: [Finding relation between matrix $S$ and matrix $M$ for wave propagation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691429/), it gave an expression for the $S$ matrix using the transfer $M$ matrix elements, which is
$$
S = \left(
\begin{matrix}
-M_{21} & \frac{1}{M_{12}} \\
M_{11}-\frac{M_{12}M_{21}}{M_{22}} & \frac{M_{12}}{M_{22}}
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$
If we also expand the definition $S=I+iT$ in 2 by 2 matrix form, we find that $M$ is not equal to $T$. Is $T$ equivalent to $M$?

Comment: I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: Transfer matrix $\ne$ transition matrix. They are quite different concepts.