# Scattering matrix and transfer matrix relationship in the case of arbitrary matrix dimensions

Tags: s-matrix-theory

Finding the relationship between scattering and transfer matrix elements is trivial in the case of 2 by 2 matrices when there are two inputs and two outputs. However, how should I approach the task of finding that relationship in the case of arbitrary matrix dimensions? Maybe this derivation is laid out in some literature but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the T-matrix for RF signals as defined here: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_parameters#Scattering_transfer_parameters) , the generalization is just to create a block matrix, where the $T_{ij}$ elements of the $2\times2$ case now each will be a matrix on their own. The total matrix is then $2n\times2n$. The $S$ matrix will also be that size and the conversion between them is a somewhat complicated block-matrix manipulation.

But the definition can give rise to mistakes, see this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/620767) and also the Wikipedia article.
As for actually doing the calculations (if you don't want to derive the procedure yourself), a quick scan does pop up a few articles:
[Reveyrand](http://microwave.fr/publications/151.pdf), or [Frei,Cai,Muller](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Multiport-%24S%24-Parameter-and-%24T%24-Parameter-With-Frei-Cai/233fc6f8287fce13c2bc31de3e1c122095b33f3f). I leave it to you to check their usefulness.

(PS: In particular Eqs. (24,25) in [Reveyrand](http://microwave.fr/publications/151.pdf) seem to be what you're looking for.)

For the other $T$ matrix concept from quantum mechanics see this [post 753784](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/753784) although in that case you have also the $M$ matrix which is similar to the above definitions, see [post 691429](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/691429).

Comment: Thank you, but that complicated block-matrix manipulation is exactly what I'm looking for..

Comment: But isn't that esentially what Eqs. (24,25) in the "Reveyrand" link are giving? (I further explain this in the edited answer now. They also further refer to the Frei article, but that isn't free downloadable, and the result is already revealed!)